# If else statement for a list with matrices

Tags: r, list, if-statement

I am learning how to properly set up loops but still struggle with the correct indexing and syntax.
Below I have a list of two matrices, 2 columns x 3 rows each.
I want to look at the second column in each matrix, and create ideally a new column with values 1 if x>0.50, else = 0. Help will be much appreciated for both ways to do it, it should help me learn. Also, if you know any good reference of structuring loops in higher dimensional lists it would be much appreciated. Thanks so much.

```
a <- c(0.1,0.2,0.3)
b <- c(0.8,0.2,0.5)
c <- c(0.4,0.9,1.0)
d <- c(0.7,0.9,0.2)
ab <- cbind(a,b)
cd <- cbind(c,d)
abcd <- list(ab,cd)

presabs <- vector("list",ncol(y))

# Trying lapply but indexing something wrong
res <- lapply(abcd, function(x) if (x[,2]>0.5) {1} else {0})

# Other method also not working:

for (i in 1:length(abcd))
        for (j in 1:length(a)){
                {
                if(abc[[i]][j]>0.50){
                        presabs[j] <- 1
                } else {
                        presabs[j] <- 0
                }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use `ifelse` or in this case it is also not needed.  The OP's question is creating a binary variable as the third column.  This can be done using many variations,

```
lapply(abcd, function(x) cbind(x,new= +(x[,2]>0.5)))
```

or

```
lapply(abcd, function(x) cbind(x,new= (x[,2]>0.5)+0L))
```

Or

```
lapply(abcd, function(x) cbind(x,new= (x[,2]>0.5)*1))
```

Or

```
lapply(abcd, function(x) cbind(x,new= as.integer(x[,2]>0.5)))
```

If the values to be changed are different, for example

```
a <- 3
b <- 2
lapply(abcd, function(x) cbind(x, new= c(a, b)[(x[,2] > 0.5)+1L]))
```

#### Benchmarks

```
set.seed(25)
abcd1 <- lapply(1:60, function(i) matrix(rnorm(1e5*2), ncol=2))
viaChris <- function() lapply(abcd1, function(x) f(x, a=1, b=0, thresh =.5))
akrun <- function() lapply(abcd1, function(x) cbind(x, lab= +(x[,2] >0.5)))

system.time(viaChris())
# user  system elapsed 
#1.683   0.000   1.444 
system.time(akrun())
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.481   0.000   0.322 

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(akrun(), viaChris(), unit='relative', times=20L)
#Unit: relative
#     expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#   akrun() 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000    20  a 
#viaChris() 3.726728 3.459581 3.475673 3.488114 3.400262 3.445557    20   b
```

Answer (score 1):

The above answer works because logical values are coerced into 1 (for `TRUE`) and 0 (for `FALSE`). A more general solution might look something like:

```
lapply(abcd, function(x) cbind(x, ifelse(x[, 2] > .5, a, b)))
```

where `a` and `b` are numeric values you can specify. We can even be more general. For example:

```
##  Define a general function that adds a new column of values
##  based on whether or not the values in the i'th column of the 
##  matrix exceeds a threshold.
f = function(x, a, b, thresh, i = 2) 
       cbind(x, lab = ifelse(x[, i] > thresh, a, b))

##  Apply the function above to each matrix in the list 'abcd', with
##  a = 1, b = 0, and thresh = .5.
lapply(abcd, function(x) f(x, a = 1, b = 0, thresh = .5))
```